# Using a comma before 'ma'

Tags: word-usage, punctuation, english-comparison

English uses a comma before *but* if, and only if, it introduces an independent sentence. Is it the same in Italian?

> - Essere sinceri è importante ma non troppo.
> - Andrei in vacanza il prossimo weekend ma non ho tempo.

In reference to above examples, can anyone explain when a comma before *ma* is needed and whether there are differences in use between Italian and English?

Comment: I would add the comma in the second sentence, but I think grammar rules are quite relaxed: I would not frown if either sentence had a comma.

Comment: @mau, I might actually do the opposite. As written, the first one almost sounds like "but it's not too important". With a comma, it sounds closer to the most likely meaning: "but don't be too sincere"; the comma allows the idea to stop, and turn around. In the second use, because of the conditional "Andrei", the "ma" clause is just complementing the idea so the comma seems unnecessary. But I think it's a style thing; I doubt that there are strong grammatical rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Italian grammars unitedly recommend using a comma before an independent clause with coordinating conjunctions *ma, anzi, però, tuttavia*.

- [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/punteggiatura)

  > Nel periodo si usa per segnalare frasi coordinate per separare dalla principale frasi coordinate introdotte da *anzi, ma, però, tuttavia* e diverse subordinate (relative esplicative, temporali, concessive, ipotetiche, non le completive e le interrogative indirette).
- [Enciclopedia  Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/virgola_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)
- [Manuale di redazione](http://books.google.se/books?id=S-x-hxAL7PQC) di Mariuccia Teroni (page 160):

  > È obbligatorio usare la virgola in alcuni casi:
  >
  > - per introdurre le frasi che cominciano con *anzi, ma, però, tuttavia*
- [Scrivere bene (o quasi)](http://books.google.se/books?id=Mw0Q7ljW5dIC) di Elisabetta Perini (page 18):

  > Normalmente la virgola si impiega nei seguenti casi:
  >
  > - per separare le proposizione coordinate introdotte dalle congiunzioni avversative *anzi, ma, però, tuttavia*

Comment: Your link to Treccani says “*per separare una proposizione da una coordinata*”; it's not the only usage of *ma*.

Comment: As @egreg said (and the same holds for Crusca's suggestions). I.M., may you modify your answer? And either remove the useless link to Teroni's book or add a relevant quote?

Answer (score 5):

When I was at the elementary school, a comma before *ma* was considered compulsory. On the other hand, a comma before *e* was a terrible sin worthy of a red sign.

If *ma* connects two adjectives

> Kyriakos è brutto ma simpatico

(I needed a name, every connection with real people is incidental `;-)`) no comma is actually required. When *ma* connects two propositions, then it's usually preceded by a comma.

In your first example, I see a slight difference between

> Essere sinceri è importante ma non troppo.

and

> Essere sinceri è importante, ma non troppo.

Adding a comma forces a pause, so in the second case I see a grin in the face of the speaker. Just a sensation, probably.

The second example is usually written with a comma and I'd use one myself. I wouldn't goggle at a missing comma, though.

Comment: _brutto ma simpatico_ connects two adjectives. _brutto, ma simpatico_ is also correct, though it places emphasis on the second adjective.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a real rule for using or not a comma in these sentences, I usually decide whether or not to use it depending on the "pause feeling" I want to give to my sentence, so that my reader can have a different perception of how would it be hearing it.

Anyway you should use a comma if the "ma" sentence is an aside comment to what is being said. For example you would write:

> Essere sinceri è importante, ma non troppo, per essere in pace con il
>   mondo.

Comment: I agree with @Frhay. As for the remark about aside comments, it is correct, but it is not specifically relevant to the use of *ma*; it would work the same way if it were *Essere sinceri è importante, anche se si è il presidente del consiglio, per essere in pace con il mondo*.

Comment: @DaG you're correct, I was just adding an example of comma usage with subordinates... :)

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a valid solution](http://www.grammatica-italiana.it/virgola.html): I'm Italian and I use the comma everytime I see a "ma".

> Per rispondere all’eterna domanda che attanaglia gli italiani “prima
>   del ma ci vuole la virgola?”, la regola più conosciuta vuole che il ma
>   avversativo utilizzato per coordinare due frasi sia preceduto da una
>   virgola, si può invece evitarla quando ad essere unite sono due frasi
>   brevi o due parole. In realtà non è sempre così, tutto dipende dalla
>   funzione delle frasi e si può decidere se l’opposizione o uno dei due
>   elementi coordinati debbano essere sottolineati dalla punteggiatura o
>   meno.

In two words: you need the comma if you are "linking two phrases" and you are giving "exception" in the 2nd phrase

> Carlo ha molti difetti, ma è simpatico e alla mano

The comma could be avoided (but usually in schools they teach to use it anyway) in short sentences. I usually use it anyway, because to me it sounds "unfamiliar".

> Carlo è brutto ma anche simpatico.

Comment: Who is “grammatica-italiana.it”?

Comment: @DaG Una tale Rossella Monaco, all'apparenza. Per carità, niente in contrario ad aprire siti personali che propongano come argomento "la grammatica italiana", ma non c'è una biografia, e inoltre chiamarlo "il portale di riferimento della lingua italiana" sarebbe troppo anche per un professorone ultraqualificato.